# Fixing the collision problem of ycb distractors with themselves as well as object of interest using rigidbody or other methods

Tags: python, objects, collision, rigidbody

TLDR: I am creating a synthetic dataset using [physics positioning in BlenderProc following BOP Linemod format](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc/tree/main/examples/datasets/bop_object_physics_positioning).

#### Describe the issue

I notice that the [ycb objects](https://www.ycbbenchmarks.com/object-set/) that I use as [distractor objects](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.11039.pdf) collide with each other and also with my object of interest. Could you please tell me how to fix it? I tried many variations of rigidbody but not sure how to fix it. I am using BlenderProc which is a Python package for Blender. You can also check [this issue](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc/issues/1072) I created.

```
    number_of_distractors = np.random.randint(0, 5)
    sampled_distractor_bop_objs = list(np.random.choice(ycbv_dist_bop_objs, size=number_of_distractors, replace=False))
    
    for obj in sampled_distractor_bop_objs:
        obj.set_shading_mode('auto')
        
        obj.enable_rigidbody(active=False, collision_shape="MESH")
        # obj.enable_rigidbody(True, mass=1.0, friction = 100.0, linear_damping = 0.99, angular_damping = 0.99, collision_margin=0.0005)
        # obj.enable_rigidbody(True, collision_shape="BOX", friction = 100.0, linear_damping = 0.99, angular_damping = 0.99) **
        # obj.enable_rigidbody(active=True, collision_shape="SPHERE")
        obj.hide(True)
```

Here is an example of ycb objects colliding with each other.

[image]

Here is the code for my object of interest:

```
    for obj in sampled_target_bop_objs:
        materials = obj.get_materials()
        for mat in materials:
            # Load one random image
            image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath=str(np.random.choice(obj_texture_images)))
            # Set it as base color of the current material
            mat.set_principled_shader_value("Base Color", image)
            mat.set_principled_shader_value("Roughness", np.random.uniform(0, 1.0))
            mat.set_principled_shader_value("Specular", np.random.uniform(0, 1.0))
        obj.enable_rigidbody(active=True, collision_shape="BOX")

        obj.hide(False)
```

Please note I am using physics for placing my objects of interest.

```
    bproc.object.sample_poses(objects_to_sample = sampled_target_bop_objs + sampled_distractor_bop_objs,  # using TLESS as distractor objc es
                            sample_pose_func = sample_pose_func, 
                            max_tries = 1000)
    
    
    # Physics Positioning
    bproc.object.simulate_physics_and_fix_final_poses(min_simulation_time=3,
                                                max_simulation_time=10,
                                                check_object_interval=1,
                                                substeps_per_frame = 20,
                                                solver_iters=25)
```

#### Minimal code example

*No response*

#### Files required to run the code

*No response*

#### Expected behavior

fix the collision problem of ycb distractor objects with each other as well as with objects of interest (target object)

#### BlenderProc version

f34774b9d835b6dada02d7ab79ab33c542f87cf3